# Scheduling a corroutine for a later loop iteration

Tags: python, tornado

I borrowed this code of a simple chat:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.gen

clients = []

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(request):
        request.render("index.html")


class WebSocketChatHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self, *args):
        print("open", "WebSocketChatHandler")
        clients.append(self)

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def on_message(self, message):

        for client in clients:
            client.write_message(message)

        @tornado.gen.coroutine
        def myroutine(m):
            print "mensaje: "
            c = (yield 123123123)
            print ("mensaje", m, c)
        yield myroutine(message)

    def on_close(self):
        clients.remove(self)

app = tornado.web.Application([(r'/chat', WebSocketChatHandler), (r'/', IndexHandler)])

app.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The Chat application works well (i.e. I see the echoes using a websocket client), and I modified it a bit to test some custom code.

And, just for testing purposes, I wanted to insert a presumably heavy function call which I wanted to make asynchronous.

The actual intention here, is that `myroutine` will start a game-engine as a paralell task.

Perhaps I am missing something, but the intention in my code is to re-schedule the corroutine in two parts. This means: the corroutine should print "message", then yield the value 123123123 (actually, this is an immediate value which will be wrapped into an already-resolved future - the value will be in the result), thus rescheduling itself to the next iteration, and (in the latter iteration) print the given tuple `("message", message, c)`.

My issue is that the function is never rescheduled (i.e. only "message:" is printed by console).

What am I doing wrong? This is my first attempt at Tornado (and async programming in general). How can I tell the tornado loop something like "dude, this value is my corruotine, and those are the arguments for my corroutine. please, start it in paralell by scheduling it in the next loop"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems going on: first, you can't yield every kind of object from a coroutine, you must yield a [Future](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.Future) or other special yieldable object. So when your coroutine yields 123123, Tornado throws a "bad yield" exception. Unfortunately, Tornado's websocket code isn't built to catch exceptions from "on_message" if "on_message" is a coroutine, so the exception passes silently. See [the warning at the bottom of the coroutine documentation](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.coroutine).

The solution for you is to yield a valid object from "mycoroutine". If you just want to yield for a moment, [yield "gen.moment"](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.moment):

```
print "one"
yield gen.moment
print "two"
```

If you want "mycoroutine" to run in parallel and not block "on_message", just call it without yielding:

```
mycoroutine(message)
```

But! Calling a coroutine this way means no one is listening to see if it throws an exception. Make sure you catch and log all exceptions within "mycoroutine", since otherwise they will pass silently.